# Find text in brackets and change certain occurrences

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have text like this

> Citation [1, 2, 3] Other Citation [2] One more Citation [3, 2]

I'm trying to replace with other numbering.

> Citation [x1, x2, x3] Other Citation [x2] One more Citation [x3, x2]

I have 200 different citations in word document.

From samples managed to hack this solution, *witch is way too slow,* **how could I improve it**?

```
    Sub ChangeText()
    Dim cDoc As Word.Document
    Dim cRng As Word.Range

    Set cDoc = ActiveDocument


    Set cRng = cDoc.Content


    cRng.Find.ClearFormatting
    With cRng.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Text = "["
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        Do While .Found
            cRng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
            cRng.MoveEndUntil Cset:="]", Count:=Word.wdForward
            For x = 1 To 200
               With cRng.FormattedText.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "[" & Cstr(x) & "]"
                .Replacement.Text = "[x" & Cstr(x) & "]"
                .Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
               End With
            Next x
            cRng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
            .Execute
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't touched VBA for years, but I think _RegExp Search & Replace_ could help you with optimizing this code

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk RegEx is usually not helpful for problems with Word's Find/Replace that should work in a *formatted* document. RegEx can only be used on strings, and strings will not carry formatting.

Answer (score -2):

So I fixed the script

```
Sub ChangeText()


    Dim cDoc As Word.Document
    Dim cRng As Word.Range
    Set cDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set cRng = cDoc.Content
    cRng.Find.ClearFormatting

    'Dim dic As Dictionary
    'Set dic = New Dictionary

    Dim c As Object
    Set c = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    c.Add "x1", "1"
    c.Add "x2", "62"
    c.Add "x3", "2"

With cRng.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Text = "["
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
    Do While .Found

        cRng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        cRng.MoveEndUntil Cset:="]", Count:=Word.wdForward

        Dim TextStr As String
        Dim Result() As String
        TextStr = cRng.FormattedText.Text
        Result() = Split(TextStr, ",")
        For i = LBound(Result()) To UBound(Result())
                Dim temp As String
                temp = CStr(LTrim(Result(i)))
                Result(i) = c(temp)
        Next i
        Debug.Print "before: " & cRng.FormattedText.Text

        cRng.FormattedText.Text = Join(Result, ", ")
        Debug.Print "after:" & cRng.FormattedText.Text
        cRng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        .Execute
    Loop
End With        
End Sub
```

Comment: If you've answered your question, could you please use the [edit] link under the answer to explain what changes were made to the code in the question? This will help others with a similar problem *understand* how to proceed. It's unlikely someone will have the exact same issue, so may need some guidance understanding the basic principle.